# python urllib error - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: urllib

I am trying out a tutorial code which fetches the html code form a website and prints it. I'm using python 3.4.0 on ubuntu. The code:

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")
print(text)
```

I saw previous solutions and tried them, I also tried importing only urllib but it still doesn't work. The error message displayed is as shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "string.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
import http.client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
from email.charset import Charset
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
import email.quoprimime
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
File "/media/saiwal/D89602199601F930/Documents/Copy/codes/python/headfirst/string.py", line 2, in <module>
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
from urllib.request import urlopen
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
import http.client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
from email.charset import Charset
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
import email.quoprimime
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
File "/media/saiwal/D89602199601F930/Documents/Copy/codes/python/headfirst/string.py", line 2, in <module>
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "string.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
import http.client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
from email.charset import Charset
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
import email.quoprimime
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
File "/media/saiwal/D89602199601F930/Documents/Copy/codes/python/headfirst/string.py", line 2, in <module>
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a nasty coincidence.

**TL;DR:** Don’t name your script `string.py`.

---

So what’s happening here?

1. You’re trying to import `urllib.request`.
2. `urllib.request` tries to import `http.client`, which tries to import `email.parser`, which tries to import `email.feedparser`, which tries to import `email.message`, which tries to import `email.utils`, which tries to import `email.charset`, which tries to import `email.quoprimime`.
3. `email.quoprimime` tries to import `string`, expecting it to be [the standard Python `string` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)—but since the current working directory has priority over the standard Python library directories, it finds your `string.py` instead and tries to import that.
4. When importing your `string.py`, you try to import `urllib.request`. Since `urllib.request` is still being imported, you get back a skeleton `urllib` without a `request` attribute yet.
5. Because your imported `string.py` then fails because it can’t find the `request` attribute, the exception starts propagating back up.
6. But wait, there’s more! Since there was an error during an import, Ubuntu tries to be helpful by seeing if you’re missing a dpkg package. If so, it could say “hey, it looks like you’re missing this module; want to `apt-get` it?” So the mechanism for looking up the appropriate package is activated…
7. …but the module for looking up the appropriate package itself depends on `urllib.request`, so it tries to import it, and again fails…

In short, because you picked `string.py` as a file name, you overrode [the standard `string` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html), which broke a lot of other modules, and even broke the module that was supposed to be helpful when you were missing a module, causing a whole lot of havoc. Fortunately the solution is easy: rename your script.

Comment: i changed the filename to string1.py and still there was an error, "ImportError: bad magic number in 'string': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'"
however using a different named worked. Can you elaborate how i can know if "string1" is causing a conflict?

Comment: @user294665: I suspect there’s a `string.pyc` file lying around from previous attempts. If you have a `__pycache__` directory in the directory containing `string1.py`, try removing it.

Comment: yes that was the exact cause! thankyou very much. it works fine now.