# Python 3.4 urllib - error

Tags: python-3.4, urllib

There is a problem, I can not understand what was going on

```
import urllib.request as gg
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261860/python-3-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-path-using-urll

Comment: What's your file's name?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367618/python-urllib-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-request

Comment: The problem is solved by renaming the script